# http POST request using webrequest C#

Tags: http, post

see the html code below it post input data to  http://demo.com/data/a.aspx

product id: 
         
         return url:

How Can I do the same thing using asp.net web form ( I mean using  asp.button server control and WebRequest(C#).

Comment: I think you forgot to attach the code

Comment: <form action="http://demo.com/data/a.aspx" method="post">
        product id: <input type="text" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="621474" />
        <br />
        return url: <input type="url" id="return_url" name="return_url" value="http://www.abc.org.nz" />
        <br />
        
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>